# How to change my file's color when it's not saved in Sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I looking for the package to know if my file is saved or not.

I tried to to find it in Sublime Text Package but I found nothing...

Anyone can help me ? thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found. I have to go in Sublime Text --> Preferences --> Setting and put : "highlight_modified_tabs": true, in User.